# Exclude auto-generated files by Django within pre-commit-config.yaml using REGEX

Tags: django, regex, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Since the auto-generated Django files don't fulfill numerous pylint-requirements, my [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) checker fails:
[image: output pylint errors]

The files look usually like so:
[image: example file]

They seem to be located automatically in a sub-folder called "migrations":
[image: auto-generated django files in migration folder]

Now, I tried to leverage the [pre-commit exclude expressions](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions) with a proper REGEX.
This one seemed to work on an [online REGEX-tester](https://regexr.com/):
`[\w-]+\d+[^\\]*.py`

Here is the proof:
[image: proof of working regex]

Now, putting this into my pylint pre-commit checker does unfortunately nothing:
[image: added exclude expression to pre-commit config YAML]

I also tried to just exclude the "migrations" folder, but I could not find a working expression either. How can I make this work?

Comment: don't post screenshots of text, they're unsearchable, uncopyable, and I can't view them in my accessibility options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your regex you tested and the regex you used are different:

```
# one you tested
[\w-]+\d+[^\\]*.py
# the one you tried
^[\w-]+\d+[^\\]*.py
```

the `^` anchors to the beginning of the string which is not what you want (your files are specifically in a subdirectory and not at the root of the repository)

additionally, slashes will always be forward slashes for pre-commit's file matching so you should instead exclude (and test against) forward slashes:

```
[\w-]+\d+[^/]*.py
```

a minor bug is you'd then match `whatever1_py` due to an un-escaped `.` (probably not a problem but here's an improvement):

```
[\w-]+\d+[^/]*\.py
```

you're also using a *javascript* regex tester -- while it doesn't matter for the features you're using here you probably want to use a *python* one as the patterns here are [python regular expressions](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions)

so try this:

```
exclude: '[\w-]+\d+[^/]*\.py'
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit, though it matters less here since this is just a regex confusion

Answer (score 3):

Use the following to match and exclude all files containing the sub-folder "migrations":

```
exclude: (migrations)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is helpful for excluding a specific folder! For the time being, I'm going to employ this solution until someone comes up with a more specific one regarding the aforementioned basename pattern of the autogenerated files.